# Javascript no pasa datos a modal

Tags: javascript, modal

estoy usando esta plantilla http://byrushan.com/projects/super-admin/app/2.1.2/modals.html la cual quiero pasar unos datos php a un modal. El mismo código que pongo mas abajo me funciona perfectamente en otra aplicación pero en esta plantilla no funciona:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $id;?>" data-id2="<?php echo $row['firstname'];?>" data-id3="<?php echo $row['lastname']; ?>"  data-id4="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>"  data-id5="<?php echo $row['password']; ?>"  data-id6="<?php echo $row['cell']; ?>" data-id7="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>" data-id8="<?php echo $row['skype']; ?>" title="Edit teacher" class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary" href="#addBookDialog">Actualizar</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="addBookDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title pull-left">Default modal</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="proposal_id" class="form-control" id="proposalId" value=""/>
                                                <label>Firstname:</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" name="firstname"  id="proposalId2" type="text" placeholder = "Firstname">
                                                <label>Lastname:</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" name="lastname"  id="proposalId3" type="text" placeholder = "Lastname">
                                                <label>Username:</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" name="un"  id="proposalId4" type="text" placeholder = "Username" readonly>
                                                <label>Password:</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" name="password"  id="proposalId5" type="text" placeholder = "Password">
                                                <label>Telephone:</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" name="telephone"  id="proposalId6" type="text" placeholder = "">
                                                <label>Email:</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" name="email"  id="proposalId7" type="email" placeholder = "">
                                                <label>Skype</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" name="skype"  id="proposalId8" type="text" placeholder = "">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Save changes</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

<script>
$(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
     var myproposalId = $(this).data('id');
     var myproposalId2 = $(this).data('id2');
     var myproposalId3 = $(this).data('id3');
     var myproposalId4 = $(this).data('id4');
     var myproposalId5 = $(this).data('id5');
     var myproposalId6 = $(this).data('id6');
     var myproposalId7 = $(this).data('id7');
     var myproposalId8 = $(this).data('id8');
     $(".modal-body #proposalId").val( myproposalId );
     $(".modal-body #proposalId2").val( myproposalId2);
     $(".modal-body #proposalId3").val( myproposalId3);
     $(".modal-body #proposalId4").val( myproposalId4);
     $(".modal-body #proposalId5").val( myproposalId5);
     $(".modal-body #proposalId6").val( myproposalId6);
     $(".modal-body #proposalId7").val( myproposalId7);
     $(".modal-body #proposalId8").val( myproposalId8);
     $('#addBookDialog').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Primero te sugiero verificar si efectivamente tienes los valores en myproposalId....myproposalId2...etc...mediante console.log(myproposalId);

Comment: una vez que sepas que si existen dichos valores... podrias poner en tus inputs asi con el ID del modal  y el ID del input ejemplo: $("#addBookDialog #proposalId").val( myproposalId );

Comment: Pues me aparece Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: en donde te aparece eso en console.log o en $("#addBookDialog #proposalId").val( myproposalId );

Comment: Exacto, y error en esto también, perdón leanmodal/js/jquery-1.12.4.min

Comment: Me aparece en console log

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79657/discussion-between-tegito123-and-vieira).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada deberias tratar de verificar que todas tus librerias carguen correctamente, en especial jquery, para usar el metodo de asignar valores al input.

Te dejo un ejemplo con bootstrap:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="form-group">
       <label>nombre:</label>
       <input type="text" id="nombre">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
       <label>Telefono:</label>
       <input type="text" id="telefono">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
  <script>
  var valor1 = "Diego Avila";
  var valor2 = "0328205126";
  //poniendo valor en modal
  $("#exampleModal #nombre").val(valor1);
    //poniendo valor en modal
  $("#exampleModal #telefono").val(valor2);
  </script>
</html>
```

Espero te sirva de guia y ayuda.. suerte !!

Comment: Perfecto, funciona a la perfección!

Comment: Gracias por todo!!!!